# KeyNotFoundException in Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am currently writing a Visual Studio Extension, creating glyph tags. First I created a example project, there is everything running fine and it's creating the glyphs. I implemented it now to my main project and got this exception, but I don't know what is missing.

> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Der angegebene Schlüssel war nicht im Wörterbuch angegeben.bei System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.GlyphMarginVisualManager`1.AddGlyph(TGlyphTag tag, SnapshotSpan span)bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.GlyphMargin`1.RefreshGlyphsOver(ITextViewLine textViewLine)bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.GlyphMargin`1.OnLayoutChanged(Object sender, TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs e)bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args) --- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde --- bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

This is my code:

```
if (classification.ClassificationType.Classification.ToLower().Contains("comment"))
                {
                    //if the word "todo" is in the comment,
                    //create a new TodoTag TagSpan
                    int index = classification.Span.GetText().ToLower().IndexOf(m_searchText);
                    if (index != -1)
                    {
                        yield return new TagSpan<IssueTag>(new SnapshotSpan(classification.Span.Start + index, m_searchText.Length), new IssueTag());
                    }
                }
```

The exception occurs at "yield return"

Comment: Could you give us the surrounding methods and functions? The stack trace shows method names but it is unclear what part exactly we're looking at here. Besides, please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).